# How to create a new record only with id

Tags: email, device, registration

Hello everyone excuse me but I am very new in RoR
I have created a small app, my goal is to create a fast registration, once registered the user if he wants, he has to fill another archive (Profile) and at the time of registration in the archive Profile is created a record with the ID of the user, so far no problem. The problem arises with the confirmation of the email because I can not find where it is confirmed in the Device. PS Excuse me, but the text is done with translate. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can override this method into your device model (e.g. User) to conditionally allow email confirmation.

```
 def confirmation_required?
   email.present? # add your condition here.
 end
```